# Bad Price WIthout Tax after adding specific price PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm having issue with calculation of price without tax, when I put price without discount it counts okay, because I made some changes in presta core, for example if I put product with price of 4,5 tax incl and 8% tax I get price - 4,17 tax excl, and that is correct.

(4,5*100)/108 = 4,16666 rounds up.

After giving specific price -15% I get price tax incl 3,83 which is correct, but I get 3,54 price tax excl which is incorrect (correct should be 3,55), I assume that everything counts using price tax excl instead of incl and counts like this

4,17 - (4,17*0,15) = 3,5445 (which php rounds to 3,54 instead of 3,55),

Do you have any idea in which controller or source file should I look to modify PrestaShop behaviour?

Comment: If you always want to round up instead of to the nearest number, use [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Comment: You might want to [edit] this to show the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside "**Product**" class, check the static method **getPriceStatic** that is basically handling everything related to retrieving a product price.

You'll end to explore **Product::priceCalculation** and many methods on the **SpecificPrice** class that are related to calculation of discounts.